# CAKEPHP - MSSQL Error When Filtering Records by Distant Association

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, relationship

So I'm a bit stuck on the above and I keep getting an sql server error. Yes I'm using mssql server :| - not my database.

A little background, my relationships concerned look like this:

AssetMaintenanceRecord->(belongs to)->Asset->(belongs to)->Project->(has one)->ProjectManager

(note ProjectManager is like an alias model for a personnel table. The project table has an id for ProjectManager which is just the personnel id.

So I'm trying to do a simple filter whereby I select all the AssetMaintenanceRecords by a search on ProjectManager.

The related index function in AssetMaintenanceRecordsController.php looks like:

```
public function index() {
        $conditions = NULL;
        if (isset($this->params['url']['report']) && $this->params['url']['report']  == 'open') {
            $conditions[] = array('CompletedDate' => NULL);
        }

        if (isset($this->params['url']['report']) && $this->params['url']['report'] == 'notified') {
            $conditions[] = array('NotifiedDate BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(date('M d Y g:iA', strtotime($this->params['url']['datefrom'])), date('M d Y g:iA', strtotime($this->params['url']['dateto']))));
        }

        if (isset($this->params['url']['report']) && $this->params['url']['report'] == 'completed') {
            $conditions[] = array('CompletedDate BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(date('M d Y g:iA', strtotime($this->params['url']['datefrom'])), date('M d Y g:iA', strtotime($this->params['url']['dateto']))));
        }

        if (isset($this->params['url']['project'])) {
            $conditions[] = array('Asset.aCurrProject' => $this->params['url']['project']);
        }

        if (isset($this->params['url']['ptCode']) && $this->params['url']['ptCode'] != NULL) {
            $conditions[] = array('Asset.ptCode' => $this->params['url']['ptCode']);
        }

        if (isset($this->params['url']['asset']) && $this->params['url']['asset'] != NULL) {
            $conditions[] = array('Asset.aFullCode' => $this->params['url']['asset']);
        }

        if (isset($this->params['url']['pm']) && $this->params['url']['pm'] != NULL) {
            $pm_search_terms = explode(' ', $this->params['url']['pm']);
            foreach($pm_search_terms as $pm_search_term) {
                $conditions[] = array(
                                'OR' => array(
                                        'ProjectManager.PerGivenName LIKE' =>'%'.$pm_search_term.'%',
                                        'ProjectManager.PerSurname LIKE' =>'%'.$pm_search_term.'%',
                                  )
                          );
            }
        }

        $this->paginate['AssetMaintenanceRecord'] = array(
            'contain' => array(
              'Asset' => array(
                'Project' => array(
                    'ProjectManager'
             ))
            ),
          'order' => 'CompletedDate ASC',
          'limit' => 10
        );

        $planttype = $this->AssetMaintenanceRecord->Asset->PlantType->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('planttype'));
        $this->AssetMaintenanceRecord->recursive = -1;
        $this->set('records', $this->paginate('AssetMaintenanceRecord', $conditions));
    }
```

Without the ProjectManager filter it works fine and I can echo out the ProjectManager array etc. but when I enter in a search term I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "ProjectManager.PerSurname" could not be bound.

The executed sql looks like:

'SELECT TOP 10 [AssetMaintenanceRecord].[MtceRegID] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord_*0], [AssetMaintenanceRecord].[AssetID] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord*_1], CAST(CAST([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[MtceRegNote] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord_*2], [AssetMaintenanceRecord].[POno] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord*_3], CAST(CAST([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[NotifiedDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord_*4], CAST(CAST([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[CompletedDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord*_5], [AssetMaintenanceRecord].[MtceRegTitle] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord_*6], CAST(CAST([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[CreatedDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord*_7], [AssetMaintenanceRecord].[CreatedUserID] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord_*8], CAST(CAST([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[ModifiedDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord*_9], [AssetMaintenanceRecord].[ModifiedUserID] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord_*10], [Asset].[aID] AS [Asset*_11], [Asset].[ptCode] AS [Asset_*12], [Asset].[aNo] AS [Asset*_13], [Asset].[aFullCode] AS [Asset_*14], [Asset].[aDesc] AS [Asset*_15], [Asset].[aMake] AS [Asset_*16], [Asset].[aModel] AS [Asset*_17], [Asset].[aSerialNo] AS [Asset_*18], [Asset].[aRegNo] AS [Asset*_19], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aRegExpDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset_*20], [Asset].[aActive] AS [Asset*_21], [Asset].[aIncAssetRpt] AS [Asset_*22], [Asset].[aIncFinanceRpt] AS [Asset*_23], [Asset].[aIsTrailer] AS [Asset_*24], [Asset].[aIsSurveyEquip] AS [Asset*_25], [Asset].[aCostedItem] AS [Asset_*26], [Asset].[aCostedPeriod] AS [Asset*_27], [Asset].[aWarrantyPeriod] AS [Asset_*28], [Asset].[aPONo] AS [Asset*_29], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aPODate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset_*30], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aPOCostExGst] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset*_31], [Asset].[aQtyStock] AS [Asset_*32], [Asset].[aQtyInUse] AS [Asset*_33], [Asset].[aCurrProject] AS [Asset_*34], [Asset].[aCurrOperator] AS [Asset*_35], [Asset].[aStolen] AS [Asset_*36], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aStolenDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset*_37], [Asset].[aWO] AS [Asset_*38], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aWODate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset*_39], [Asset].[aSold] AS [Asset_*40], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aSoldDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset*_41], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aSoldPrice] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset_*42], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aNotes] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset*_43], CAST(CAST([Asset].[LastModDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset_*44], CAST(CAST([Asset].[CreatedDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset*_45], [Asset].[aCat] AS [Asset_*46], [Asset].[aPoliceRptNo] AS [Asset*_47], [Asset].[aRelatedAssetID] AS [Asset_*48], [Asset].[aRelatedAssetFullCode] AS [Asset*_49], [Asset].[aPayMethod] AS [Asset_*50], [Asset].[aInvoiceNo] AS [Asset*_51], CAST(CAST([Asset].[aLastFuelDate] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS [Asset_*52], [Asset].[aFuelType] AS [Asset*_53] FROM [tbMtceRegister] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord] LEFT JOIN [tbAsset] AS [Asset] ON ([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[AssetID] = [Asset].[aID]) WHERE [CompletedDate] IS NULL AND [Asset].[aCurrProject] IS NULL AND (([ProjectManager].[PerGivenName] LIKE '%test%') OR ([ProjectManager].[PerSurname] LIKE '%test%')) ORDER BY [CompletedDate] ASC'

Looks ok to me but I'm obviously going wrong somwhere?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProjectManager is not contained in `FROM` or `JOIN` Part 
but used in `WHERE` :  `OR ([ProjectManager].[PerSurname] LIKE`

Comment: Oh yes I can see that... so how would I go about joining the ProjectManager/Project to the query? (sql is definitely no my strong suit).

Comment: I don't know your namings in SQL something like
join ProjectManager on ProjectManager.ID=Project.ProjectManager_ID
left join if it's possible that no manager is assigned

Comment: Ok so I tried doing the joins like this: `$this->paginate['AssetMaintenanceRecord'] = array(
      'contain' => array(
     'Asset' => array(
    'Project' => array(
     'ProjectManager'
    ))
   ),
    'order' => 'CompletedDate ASC',
       'limit' => 10,
    'joins' => array(
   array('table' => 'tbPersonnel',
    'alias' => 'ProjectManager',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array(
     'ProjectManager.perID = Project.pjProjectManager',
    )
   )
    )
  );`

Comment: Whoops... continued... and I get error: The multi-part identifier "Project.pjProjectManager" could not be bound.   Tried joining Project as well get error about Asset.xxx could not be bound. Try to join Asset also and get error that identifier Asset has been used already, change to Asset2, it returns the same record thousands of times... query looks like:
[link](http://pastebin.com/txAUKDJ7)

Comment: this should work, only the where part ....
FROM [tbMtceRegister] AS [AssetMaintenanceRecord] 
 JOIN [tbAsset] AS [Asset] ON ([AssetMaintenanceRecord].[AssetID] = [Asset].[aID]) 
 JOIN [tbProject] AS [Project] ON ([Project].[pjID] = [Asset].[aCurrProject]) 
 LEFT JOIN [tbPersonnel] AS [ProjectManager] ON ([ProjectManager].[perID] = [Project].[pjProjectManager]) 

 WHERE [CompletedDate] IS NULL AND

Comment: Thankyou for the example. So I'm a step closer and a step further away. Based on your example above I used the joinable behaviour plugin to setup the joins. And it works, it returns the AssetMaintenanceRecords by ProjectManager. However, previously it would return the Assets/Projects as an array but now if I use contain or set recursive to 2 it wants to use the Asset correlation name again therefore I get "The correlation name 'Asset' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause." Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: OK massive hack but just created a copy of the Asset model and named it Asset2. Used Asset2 in contain and Asset in the join. Works though. Thanks Bummi.